# Extraer datos de TextBox multiLine c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialport, textbox

estoy recibiendo mediante un serial port RS232 de una balanza de camiones la siguiente secuencia de caracteres en un textBox multiLine. 
Lo que yo quisiera hacer es extraer el peso "1060".
Veo que la cadena de caracteres tiene 4 lineas: comienza con , le sigue el 1, le sigue el peso 1060, y por último el cero. 
Como extraigo el 1060 a un texBox nuevo o Label? Solo eso quisiera poder hacer. Gracias infinitas de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: donde observas las 4 lineas ?

Comment: Como verás el String que recibo es 
Linea 1:          1
Linea 2:      1060
Linea 3:        0
Y se repite de nuevo.  Más bien son 3 lineas que se repiten cuando recibo datos.

Comment: pero veo 6 linea al inicio con cero, quizas pusiste un ejemplo de archivo incorrecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para leer el archivo podrias usar `File.ReadAllLines()` entonces a estas las iteras hasta conseguir a linea con el valor

```
string lineas = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\...\archivo.txt");

int index = 0;
foreach(var linea in lineas)
{
   string result = Regex.Replace(linea, @"[^\d.]", "");

   int nro = 0;
   int.TryParse(result, out nro);

   if(nro == 1){
        break;
   }
   index++;
}

string strPeso= Regex.Replace(linea[index + 1], @"[^\d.]", "");
int peso = Convert.ToInt32(strPeso);
```

La idea es que iteres hasta encontrar el `1`, entonces conociendo ese indice de las lineas del archivo tomas la siguiente que seria el peso.

Si necesitas ir leyendo el resto de las lineas para obtener los valores

```
List<int> pesos = new List<int>();

int index = 0;
foreach(var linea in lineas)
{
    string result = Regex.Replace(linea, @"[^\d.]", "");

    int nro = 0;
    int.TryParse(result, out nro);

    if(nro == 1)
    {
        index++;
        string strPeso= Regex.Replace(linea[index], @"[^\d.]", "");
        int peso = Convert.ToInt32(strPeso);

        pesos.Add(peso);
    }

    index++;
}
```

podrias no cortar con un `break` sino continuar la lectura, pero vas a tener que ir poniendo los valores en una lista para tener todos los pesos

Comment: Leandro, tu código funciona perfecto con el archivo .txt
Como puedo reemplazar la ruta del archivo por mi textBox? es decir, que en tiempo real me realice el mismo proceso que mencionas a un textBox multiLine mientras se va escribiendo. Por ejemplo en una linea escribo "1" y en la siguiente "1060" entonces tomar el dato del textBox. 
Pdta: me leí muchos post tuyos genio. Increíble que me contestes uno.

Comment: Leandro perfecto!! solo cambié la ruta del archivo por  textBox1.Lines (sacado de un post tuyo) y funciona en mi textBox.
Ahora lo único que falta es que me lea tras cada ultima actualización. Es decir que lea el último "1" y me muestre el último resgistro siguiente. Por ahora solo lo realiza con el primer 1 y el registro siguiente a éste.

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando una opcion para continuar la lectura, analizala quizas te da una pista

Comment: Muchas gracias. Perfecto todo.